# Javascript code to struts2

Tags: javascript, struts2

how to write the below code using struts2 tag library. since struts2 have many tags like iterator, if etc. but how the below code can be achieved using that?

how we can initialize variable in struts2 tag and after that how to apply increment or decrements operation like the code shown below?

```
int j=-1;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
j++;
if(j==0)
{
}
if(j==1)
{
}
if(j==2)
{
j=-1;
}
}
```

This is my jsp page where i used the java code within the scriplet tags

```html
<h3>Our Latest Projects</h3>
<%! int j = -1; %>

<%
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    j++;
%>
  <% if (j == 0) { %>
<div class="wrapper">
  <article class="grid_4 alpha">
    <h4 class="p2">Project 1</h4>
    <figure><a href="#"><img class="img-border" src="images/page4-img1.jpg" alt=""/></a></figure>
    <div class="box" style="height: 20px; width: 257px;">
      <div class="padding">
        <a href="#">View Details</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <% } %>

  <% if (j == 1) { %>
  <article class="grid_4">
    <div class="indent-left4">
      <h4 class="p2">Project 2</h4>
      <figure><a href="#"><img class="img-border" src="images/page4-img2.jpg" alt=""/></a></figure>
      <div class="box" style="height: 20px; width: 257px;">
        <div class="padding">
          <a href="#">View Details</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <% } %>
  <% if (j == 2) { %>
  <article class="grid_4 omega">
    <div class="indent-left3">
      <h4 class="p2">Project 3</h4>
      <figure><a href="#"><img class="img-border" src="images/page4-img3.jpg" alt=""/></a></figure>
      <div class="box" style="height: 20px; width: 257px;">
        <div class="padding">
          <a href="#">View Details</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
<br><br>
<% j = -1; %>
<% } %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Why do you even care? There's no S2 data; what's the point? This is a complete mess. Is there a bug regarding the first block, since I *think* it will appear twice? Is that a static `j`? What's the *goal*?

Comment: but is there no solution for  int j=-1;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
j++;
if(j==0)
{
}
if(j==1)
{
}
if(j==2)
{
j=-1;
}
}   in STRUTS2

Comment: It's impossible to even guess what you're trying to do. I'm editing out all the embedded CSS so I can even begin to read this.

Comment: Struts 2 is not an acronym. You'd use the `<s:iterator>` tag, but why bother when there's JSTL `<c:forEach>`? You're not accessing any S2 data. Why use an S2 tag? Ugh.

Comment: Do you *want* the first block to show up twice?

Comment: actually the count i.e here that is 4, have to be retrieved through session in struts2 tag which i did like #session.cust.count but i don't know how to do the rest of the code i'e the checking , increment and decrement using struts2 tags

Comment: Struts2 version is 2.1.8

Comment: Too bad; s:iterator has a begin/end in later versions. Use JSTL's forEach instead. Not sure what the goal is, i.e., how you want to style each of the articles, based on the count. Impossible to read this.

Comment: sir my intention is that in the jsp page 3projects can be placed in a row suppose the session count is 4 then 3 must be in one row and the last one will be at the second row..for that i coded in java which works fine but i want tat to be done using struts2 tags

Comment: And I'm saying that the S2 iterator tag doesn't allow trivial iteration until later S2 version than you're using. Or if you even need it, seems like you could just iterate over a list of projects instead of using numbers; the code in my answer is the same except for the iterator tag. If I were doing it I'd put dummy projects so it's an even multiple of the number of columns you want just to make things easier in the view layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a disaster.

Here's everything except for the `article > div` styling since it wasn't clear how it was related to anything else; you should be able to figure it out based on the rest of this code.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <s:iterator begin="1" end="#session.count" status="stat">
    <s:set var="artClass" value="#stat.first ? 'alpha' : #stat.last ? 'omega' : ''" />

    <article class="grid_4 <s:property value="#artClass"/>">
      <div> <!-- Not really sure what you want here for the class. -->
        <h4 class="p2">Project <s:property value="#stat.count"/></h4>
        <figure><a href="#"><img class="img-border" src="images/page4-img<s:property value="#stat.count"/>.jpg" alt=""/></a></figure>
        <div class="box" style="height: 20px; width: 257px;">
          <div class="padding">
            <a href="#">View Details</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </s:iterator>
</div>
```

Also, if "alpha" and "omega" are for the first and last columns, and not the first/last items in the list, you'd want to change this up somewhat. Personally, I would split the list up into a list of threes in the Java code and do a double-iteration:

```html
<s:iterator value="listOfLists" var="list">
  <s:iterator value="list" status="stat">
    <s:set var="artClass" value="#stat.first ? 'alpha' : #stat.last ? 'omega' : ''" />

    <article class="grid_4 <s:property value="#artClass"/>">
      <div> <!-- Not really sure what you want here for the class. -->
        <h4 class="p2">Project <s:property value="#stat.count"/></h4>
        <figure><a href="#"><img class="img-border" src="images/page4-img<s:property value="#stat.count"/>.jpg" alt=""/></a></figure>
        <div class="box" style="height: 20px; width: 257px;">
          <div class="padding">
            <a href="#">View Details</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </s:iterator>
  <br/><br/> <!-- Use CSS. -->
</s:iterator>
```

You could also encapsulate this in a custom tag and utility method and make things very clean.

Comment: @Dave, Do we need use <s:set/> with in iterator here? It will be checked each and every time.

Comment: @MohanaRaosv If you want to set something on every iteration, yes. You *could* use an if/else, but there's no point.

Comment: @user1575570 The list implementation doesn't matter. I mean a list of lists, in your example, each list would have a list of three elements-the columns.